# Two strings evaluated by regex, but one of the scan results are being put into an extra array?

Tags: ruby, regex

I can't figure out what I'm doing different in the below example. I have two string which in my perspective are similar - plain strings. For each string I have a regex, but the first regex, `/\*Hi (.*) \*,/`, gives me a result where the regex match is presented in 2 arrays: `[["result"]]`. I need my result to be presented in just 1 array: `["result"]`. What am I doing differently in the 2 below examples?

```
✗ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > name_line_1 = "*Hi Peter Parker *,"
 => "*Hi Peter Parker *," 
2.0.0p247 :002 > name_line_1.scan(/\*Hi (.*) \*,/)
 => [["Peter Parker"]] 
2.0.0p247 :003 > name_line_2 = "Peter Parker<br />Memory Lane 60<br />0000 Gotham<br />USA<br />TEL:: 00000000000<br /><a href=\"mailto:peter5064@parker.com\">peter@parker.com</a><br />\r"
 => "Peter Parker<br />Memory Lane 60<br />0000 Gotham<br />USA<br />TEL:: 00000000000<br /><a href=\"mailto:peter5064@parker.com\">peter@parker.com</a><br />\r" 
2.0.0p247 :004 > name_line_2.scan(/^[^<]*/)
 => ["Peter Parker"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scan` returns an array of matches. As the other answers point out, if your regex has capturing groups (parentheses), that means *each* match will return an array, with one string for each capturing group within the match.

If it didn't do this, `scan` wouldn't be very useful, as it is very common to use capturing groups in a regex to pick out different parts of the match.

I suspect that `scan` is not really the best method for your situation. `scan` is useful when you want to get *all* the matches from a string. But in the string you show, there is only one match anyways. If you want to get a specific capturing group from the first match in a string, the easiest way is:

```
 string[/regex/, 1] # extract the first capturing group, or nil if there is no match
```

Another way is to do something like this:

```
 if string =~ /regex/
   # $1 will contain the first capturing group from the first match
```

Or:

```
 if match = string.match(/regex/)
   # match[1] will contain the first capturing group
```

If you really want to get *all* matches in the string, and need to use a capturing group (or feel it's more readable than using lookahead and lookbehind, which it is):

```
 string.scan(/regex/) do |match|
   # do something with match[0]
 end
```

Or:

```
 string.scan(/regex/).map(&:first)
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because you are capturing the name in name_line_1 using parentheses. This causes the scan method to return an array of arrays. If you absolutely must return a 1 dimensional array, you can use forward and backward checking like so:

```
/(?<=\*Hi ).*(?= \*,)/
```

Or, if you find that too confusing, you could always just call `.flatten` on the resulting array ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that, in the first regex, you have *captured substring* `()`. When a regex matches, the whole match is captured as `$&`, and in addition to that, you can capture parts of it as many as you want by using `()`. They will be captured as `$1`, `$2`, ...

And `scan` behaves differently depending whether you have `$1`, `$2`, ... When you don't, then it returns an array of all `$&`s. When you do have `$1`, `$2`, ..., then it returns an array of `[$1, $2, ...]`.

In order to avoid `$1` in the first regex, you have to avoid using captured substring: